# How to Do Basic Computations in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade, computation

I'm trying to do computations on Laravel to show the annual interest rate and show it on my blade file. I'm not sure if this is possible directly on the blade file or I should do the computations on my controller then pass it on my blade view.

So far I tried directly on the blade file

```
<div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-warning text-uppercase mb-1">Annual Return</div>
<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php  {{ $amountSum * 12% }}</div>
```

but it doesn't work and I get an error

```
ParseError syntax error, unexpected ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\fss\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)
```

In my controller, I have

```
 public function dashboard()
{
    $moneytrades = MoneyTrade::all();
    $moneytradeDeposits = MoneyTradeDeposit::all();
    $amountSum = MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount');

    return view('dashboard', compact('moneytrades', 'moneytradeDeposits', 'amountSum'));
}
```

I've tried adding `$annual = $amountSum * 12%` on my controller as well but I'm writing it wrong. How can I possibly do this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe the ℅. Try `$amountSum * 12 / 100`

Comment: Wow that was an easy fix! Thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: To clarify, anything in `{{ }}` is treated as PHP code. As such, the `%` is the modulus operator, and not the 'percent sign'. Since there's nothing to the right of the operator, the code fails as a syntax error. If you simply moved that outside of the `{{ }}`, like `{{ ($amount * 12) / 100 }}%`, then you'd have something like `30%` once the code is compiled to HTML.

Comment: Oh now I understand. Thank you very much for that helpful information. I'm just starting with Laravel and every information is much appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help! The `{{ }}` syntax can be a little confusing as first, but as long as you keep in mind that anything between the braces is PHP and not HTML, you're good to go :) The error message is a little vague here too, since it's referencing the compiled version (adding an extra `)` for example), but it'll make sense when you see it a few times. Cheers!

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I ask how can I make a calculation based on form inputs? For example I have an `<input type="text" name="amount1">` and another input `<input type="text" name="amount2">` wherein the user would input values and I want to add those 2 and show it on a 3rd input, can I use `{{ }}` and put the name of the inputs there as variable or do I do this on a controller instead?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this according to  @porloscerros Ψ help where I changed

```
{{ $amountSum * 12% }}
```

to

```
{{ $amountSum * 12 / 100 }}
```

as the % sign is causing the error. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just do the percent calculation as below:

```
<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php  {{ ($amountSum * 12) / 100 }}%</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works for me. Can I ask how can I make a calculation based on form inputs? For example I have an <input type="text" name="amount1"> and another input <input type="text" name="amount2"> wherein the user would input values and I want to add those 2 and show it on a 3rd input, can I use {{ }} and put the name of the inputs there as variable or do I do this on a controller instead?

Comment: In this situation, you have to write javascript code to instantly calculate the values of input and show the calculated result. And this {{}} will not work because server side code just run at first rendering od page when you reload it.

Comment: Oh I see. Okay I'll try that. Thanks again!